# How should I parametrize a nonlinear increasing function?

Tags: nonlinear, gradient-descent, parameterization

I want to learn a nonlinear monotone increasing function $f$ parametrized using a set of weights $w$.  Given an input $x$, I can calculate the gradient of the loss with respect to $f(x)$ $\nabla_{f(x)} L$.  Then I hope to update $w$ by gradient descent.  Ideally, the gradient would be focused on a small set of the parameters $w$ to mitigate the credit assignment problem.  I feel like the monotonicity should greatly simplify this problem. Is there any research on this topic?

For example, the parameters could be a set of $z_1 < z_2 < \dots < z_n$ and a corresponding set of $y_i > 0$.  Then $f(x)$ could be the interpolated value assuming that it is piecewise linear through the points $(z_i, \sum_{j=1}^i y_j)$.  This does not seem easy to train.

Comment: can you explain that with an example?

Comment: @hamed: You want me to answer my own question?

Comment: :) no but just explain that more. Your question is not clear to me.

Comment: @hamed: I added an example.

Answer (score -1):

Presume f_fitted(x) is your fitted function. You will have to choose a parameterization. But per your example, piecewise linear is a possibility. You could use fixed break points or have them chosen in the fitting procedure. You could use cross validation to choose the optimal number of break points.

The key to achieving your stated aim of fitting a function which is monotonically increasing is to impose such a condition as part of the fitting optimization problem.  So you want derivative of f_fitted(x) >= 0 at all points at which is is defined. It may not be defined at break points if you use linear functions between the break points. So, say you have fitted lines between each break point, you need to impose the  constraint that slope >= 0 for each segment.  Also impose for all i the continuity constraint that the fitted function between x_i and x_i+1 is equal at x_i+1 to the fitted function between x_i+1 and x_i+2. Together, these constraints will ensure a monotonically increasing continuous function.

You can use the same kind of ideas with functions (basis) other than piecewise linear.  In fact, this is roughly the kind of thing that's done in spline regression, except that derivative continuity rather than monotonicity might be imposed

So think of training as fitting, and think of fitting as an optimization problem. Impose the constraints you want as part of the optimization problem. Reading chapter 5 of [Hastie, Tibshirani, Friedman 'The Elements of Statistical Learning'](http://statweb.stanford.edu/~tibs/ElemStatLearn/printings/ESLII_print10.pdf) may give you ideas on choosing basis functions and how to go about the fitting in general, since perhaps piecewise linear functions may not be a great choice.

Comment: Is this not an adequate answer? Do you need more help?

Comment: Sorry for the late reply. I don't see your comments unless you precede them with "@NeilG".  The first two paragraphs of your answers are a good explanation of my question.  I took a look at the chapter you mentioned.  However, I could only find things related to spline fitting.  I think that there is a lot of structure in my problem that spline fitting does not take advantage of.  For example, when you discover that for some `x`, `f(x)` is too small, you can increase not only nearby control points, but sometimes also all of the following control points.

Comment: In short, I don't think that curve fitting is a good solution to my problem because it doesn't make use of the constraint of monotonicity.

Comment: @Neil G , as I indicated, you can impose constraints to enforce monotonicity. You need to adapt the book material to impose the constraints you want/need.

Comment: I'm not sure how to do that in a way that gets the most information from each data point. This answer would be better if it were more explicit.  That is, I need to know the model parameters $\theta$, and how to update these parameters given $x$ and the gradient of the loss with respect to $f(x)$.  Saying "read this chapter and apply your constraints" is more a restatement of my problem than it is a clear answer.

Comment: Well, I don't even have your data, and don't plan to do the detailed fitting for you even if I did.   Some things require an effort to be put in.  I gave you an example with your example of how to put the constraints in.  For other models, the method would be different.

Comment: My question is to come up with a model.  It's not obvious to me how to turn your answer into an algorithm.  If it's obvious to you, maybe you'd like to clarify your answer.  Many of the curve-fitting methods don't even accept data in the form I specified in the question: as triplets $x, \hat f(x), \nabla_{\hat f(x)}{L}$ — they instead want pairs $x, f(x)$.

Comment: Another problem with this answer is that it enforces the constraints after the fact whereas I think it would be better for the model design to take them into account.  E.g., if I said that I wanted to do gradient descent with all the parameters positive, you might say, just do gradient descent and clip your parameters after the fact.  It's better in general to make it so that the model itself never gets into trouble in the first place by for example putting the parameters in log space.  Similarly, in this problem it would be better to enforce the constraints by a clever model specification.

Comment: Perhaps you don't understand how optimization works. Constraints which are provided to the solver are not "after the fact".  Yes, you should be smart about your model specification and parameterization. If all you know about optimization is unconstrained gradient descent, you don't know what optimization is and can do.

Comment: Forgot this machine learning stuff for the moment. Take a course in nonlinear optimization, where among other things, you'll learn about constrained optimization - how to formulate problems, and how to solve them.  You know neither.

Comment: " if I said that I wanted to do gradient descent with all the parameters positive, you might say, just do gradient descent and clip your parameters after the fact"  You (people who think optimization = gradient descent) might say that, I wouldn't.

Comment: This problem is part of a larger problem in which I only have inputs and gradients.  I can't change that.  If you can't provide a solution that makes use of those inputs and gradients, then you're not answering my problem.  I appreciate that you put some effort into your answer, but I think we can both agree that it doesn't answer the question I asked.

Comment: Please search this site for "monotone spline", there are multiple posts with examples now!